# Simple redirection with countdown

Tags: redirects

I would like to redirect visitors to my new website. I would like to show a page where there is a countdown "you will be directed to the new site by 4..5..3..2..1 seconds" but I would like the user to choose whether to stay on the old one by clicking on a link, before the countdown expires.
How can I make it practically? My old site is based on Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want both a countdown and allow the user to interrupt the countdown, this would typically be done with JavaScript.  Check this example on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/Joel-James/62d98e8cb3a1b6b05102).  If you have further questions, StackOverflow is better place since this is more of a coding question than a web mastering question.

Comment: yes the script is fine. I just wanted to know on which page I need to insert the script. keep in mind that I have a site made in drupal.

Comment: @user63747 the JavaScript goes on the page that you are redirecting from.  I.e., from the old page the user first sees before the redirect.  I'm not familiar with Drupal, but you should be able to add JavaScript to the header of the page the user lands on.

Comment: I would like the script to work from any page on the site. maybe I should use a special component?

Comment: @user63747 look at https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2017-10-19/how-to-add-a-css-and-a-js-to-all-pages-of-a-site

Comment: I placed the redirect.js file in the same location as the .info file. then I added this line to the end of the .info file
scripts [] = redirect.js
does not work!

Comment: @user63747, unfortunately, this is neither a Drupal nor a programming forum, it's specifically for managing web servers.  I would suggest you ask a new question in the Drupal forum that I provided.